# Is there a keyword/way to specify working directory without manually typing out the path?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

If I want to change the group of the directory I'm in to root, I assumed the command would be: 
`sudo chgrp root` but then I end up getting a `chgrp: missing operand after ‘root’`. Is there a keyword or shortcut that specifies the working directory without having to type out the path manually? Had trouble finding anything through google, thanks.

Comment: `$PWD` will contain the working directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every directory, `.` represents the directory itself:

```
sudo chgrp root .
```

will change the group owning the current directory.